# Unity C# how should I call the function and values from different script files?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am new to Unity and c#. I am trying to create a dice game that rolls two dices and the total values of the two dice faces is added to the player's score. I am intending the game to continue until the player rolls two 1's or the total score reached or exceeds 50, and at the end display win or lose message and the score. I somehow managed to implement most of it. However, I can't manage to update score after rolling the dice. I tried on my own to do so, but now it's keep adding the dice rolls without break and prints win message right away.

This is the Dice code

```
public class Dice : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody rb;
    bool hasLanded;
    bool thrown;
    Vector3 initPosition; //Initial Position
    
    public int diceValue;
    public DiceSide[] diceSides;
    
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        initPosition = transform.position;
        rb.useGravity = false;
    }
    
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            RollDice();
        }
    
        if(rb.IsSleeping() && !hasLanded && thrown)
        {
            hasLanded = true;
            rb.useGravity = false;
            //rb.isKinematic = true;
    
            SideValueCheck();
    
        }
        else if(rb.IsSleeping() && hasLanded && diceValue == 0)
        {
            RollAgain();
        }
    }
    
    void RollDice()
    {
        if(!thrown && !hasLanded)
        {
            thrown = true;
            rb.useGravity = true;
            rb.AddTorque(Random.Range(0, 500), Random.Range(0, 500), Random.Range(0, 500));
        }
        else if(thrown && hasLanded)
        {
            Reset();
        }
    
    }
    
    void Reset()
    {
        transform.position = initPosition;
        thrown = false;
        hasLanded = false;
        rb.useGravity = false;
        //rb.isKinematic = false;
    }
    
    void RollAgain()
    {
        Reset();
        thrown = true;
        rb.useGravity = true;
        rb.AddTorque(Random.Range(0, 500), Random.Range(0, 500), Random.Range(0, 500));
    
    }
    
    void SideValueCheck()
    {
        diceValue = 0;
        foreach (DiceSide side in diceSides)
        {
            if (side.OnGround())
            {
                diceValue = side.sideValue;
                Debug.Log(diceValue + " has been rolled!");
    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the sides code(just in case. not really relevant to the problem I am having but I am still attaching just in case)

```
public class DiceSide : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool onGround;
    public int sideValue;
    
    void OnTriggerStay(Collider col)
    {
        if(col.tag == "Ground")
        {
            onGround = true;
        }
    }
    
    void OnTriggerExit(Collider col)
    {
        if(col.tag == "Ground")
        {
            onGround = false;
        }
    }
    
    public bool OnGround()
    {
        return onGround;
    }

}
```

and here's the code I am having the hardest time with...

```
public class Check : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject DiceGameObject1;
    public GameObject DiceGameObject2;
    private Dice dice;
    private Dice dice2;
    
    public int dicevalue1;
    public int dicevalue2;
    
    private int score;
    private int totalScore;
    public TMP_Text Score;
    public TMP_Text TotalScore;
    public TMP_Text Win;
    public TMP_Text Lose;
    public TMP_Text Player;
    
    
    void Start()
    {
        totalScore = 0;
        score = 0;
        Win.text = "";
        Lose.text = "";
    }
    
    void Awake()
    {
        dice = DiceGameObject1.GetComponent<Dice>();
        dice2 = DiceGameObject2.GetComponent<Dice>();
    }
    
    void Update()
    {
        UpdateScore();
    }
    
    void SetScoreText()
    {
        if (dicevalue1 == 1 && dicevalue2 == 1)
        {
            Lose.text = "You Lose:(";
        } 
        else if (totalScore >= 50)
        {
            Win.text = "You win!";
        }
        else
        {
            TotalScore.text = totalScore.ToString();
        }
    }
    
    public void UpdateScore()
    {
        dicevalue1 = dice.diceValue;
        dicevalue2 = dice2.diceValue;
        score = dicevalue1 + dicevalue2;
        Debug.Log(dicevalue1 + dicevalue2);
        // how do I import diceValue variables from Dice class and use the values here?
        totalScore += score;
        SetScoreText();
    }
}
```

So I first had problem using the diceValue variable(value) from Dice script at Check script, but I somehow managed to. I am quite not understanding how, but I tried GetComponent from Dice file to make it somehow work. I was wondering if I should do that with UpdateScore method as well, but I am stuck...

Eventually I am trying to make this a turn-based two-player game, where player take turns. So far I barely managed it to work as one player game...
Please help!!

Comment: just out of interest did you indeed inert the Dice sides? currently you are checking which one is on the ground to define the points - sounds a bit counter intuitive

Comment: why do you call `UpdateScore` each and every frame? You should only do that **once** after both dices have finished rolling

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `UpdateScore()` in `Update()`. `Update()` is called every frame, so when your `SideValueCheck()` has evaluated a dice number, the score will rise very quickly to 50. What you need is a condition to query when the dice numbers have been evaluated such that you update the score only once. You  could add in your `Check` class a new flag `bool scoreUpdated = false;` and change `UpdateScore()` to

```
public void UpdateScore()
{
    
    dicevalue1 = dice.diceValue;
    dicevalue2 = dice2.diceValue;
    // only update if not done already and the dice have meaningful side values
    if (!scoreUpdated && dicevalue1 != 0 && dicevalue2 != 0) {
        score = dicevalue1 + dicevalue2;
        Debug.Log(dicevalue1 + dicevalue2);
        // how do I import diceValue variables from Dice class and use the values here?
        // (Edit: you did that already)
        totalScore += score;
        scoreUpdated = true; // track the score update
        SetScoreText();
    }
}
```

Now, if you do a new dice roll, you need to first reset the dice value of the rolling dice. `Reset()` would be edited to:

```
void Reset()
{
    transform.position = initPosition;
    thrown = false;
    hasLanded = false;
    diceValue = 0;  // the dice is rolling again, so no valid side value
    rb.useGravity = false;
    //rb.isKinematic = false;
}
```

and of course you need to reset the score tracking which you could do maybe in `Update()` of `Dice` class, because you located the input code there:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        RollDice();
        check.scoreUpdated = false;
    }
```

How to get `check`? I dont know where you attached it, but you need to get a reference to that game object and then get the script component on it with `Check check = go.GetComponent<Check>();` just like you did with the dice variables.

Comment: Thank you so much! However, I tried implementing Check check = go.GetComponent<Check> and I keep having error CS0122, saying the name 'go' does not exist. If you don't mind can you elaborate how to implement Check check with detail? Should I try implementing it like GameObject like I did with DiceObject? I thought it was not applicable here

Comment: The `Check` script must be attached to some game object. You could for example find it with `GameObject go = GameObject.Find("Name");` where "Name" is the name of that game object. `GameObject.Find` is not an efficient method though, but it should suffice for a start.

Comment: Sadly my Check script is attached to the canvas(UI) on unity, and I believe I can't consider canvas as a game object .. would there be alternative solution by any chance? I tried creating a public bool scoreUpdated(){ return scoreUpdated;) in Check class instead so that I can use it at Dice class, but that seems to not work as well

Comment: Why do you believe the Canvas is not a GameObject? As the docs https://docs.unity3d.com/2023.1/Documentation/Manual/UICanvas.html say: "The Canvas is a Game Object with a Canvas component on it". Did you try to get the reference with `GameObject.Find("Canvas")` or whatever you named it?

Comment: Oh now I understand. I was trying to create a tag name go, and add that tag to canvas. For some reason when I was trying to add a tag to Canvas and has that tag value to use find Component function, it wasn't working. I will try that! Thanks!